# Get path to dll loaded using LoadLibrary("MyDll.dll")

Tags: winapi, loadlibrary

I'm loading a dll by using it's name like this:

HANDLE hlib = LoadLibrary("Winfax.dll");

Now I want to know from which path the dll was loaded. Is there a way to get the full path and file name for  a dll handle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out GetModuleFileName: [GetModuleFileName Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197(VS.85).aspx) using hlib as the HMODULE.