# Determine the path of a *.dll or *.so at runtime

Tags: c++

A C++ library must read a file from disk that is located in the same directory as the library. I don't know if the question is trivial or if it is impossible: How can the library determine its own path on disk? The solution should work for Linux (*.so) and Windows (*.dll).

Comment: Both platforms behave different - choose one. They also behave differently in terms of shared libraries

Comment: So I need two seperate solutions for Windows and Linux.

Comment: Yes - they are different. It is like saying you want a vegetarian salad in Germany and then you spend the rest of the evening removing the ham seasoning from the lettuce

Comment: OK, so I'd like to ask for solutions for both platforms.

Comment: Why do you want to know the path?

Comment: The lib needs to read a file that comes with the lib. In the current case it is a JavaScript code that will be copied when the library creates some *.html code.

Comment: When the library is creating this html surely it knows where. Probably independent of the location of the library. Guess you do not want the library in the website

Comment: The mylib.dll and myJavaScript.js are located in $unknownPath. The user of the library compiles hisApplication.exe and links it with mylib.dll. hisApplication.exe calls the library-method writeHTML("outputPath") and the library needs to write an *.html and to copy myJavaScript.js there. The question is, how to determine $unknownPath ?

Comment: Current working directory is the best bet

Comment: Under Linux rpath can be used, so it is at least not a solution for Linux. Under Windows, when the user is at the command line in directory c:\ and launches c:\appdir\application.exe, then the working directory is still c:\ (at least I think so, I develop most of the time under Linux)

Answer (score 4):

Although the task you describe is usually solved in a different fashion, here's the solution for Linux:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

void foo() {
    Dl_info dlInfo;
    dladdr(puts, &dlInfo);
    if (dlInfo.dli_sname != NULL && dlInfo.dli_saddr != NULL)
        printf("puts is loaded from %s\n", dlInfo.dli_fname);
    else
        printf("It's strange but puts is not found\n");
    puts("Hello, world! I'm foo!");
}
```

Here the source of `puts` function is determined using [dladdr](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlsym).

For Windows see [this recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117462/get-path-to-dll-loaded-using-loadlibrarymydll-dll)

When I told that the task is solved differently I meant the following. In Linux (and oher "typical unix-like system") shared libraries are separated from the rest of "application data" (the former reside in `/lib`, `/lib64`, `/usr/lib` or `/usr/lib64`, depending on target platform, "importance of a particular library" and other factors, the latter typically go to `/usr/share/<appname>`). That is the path to library won't help you. Path to application data files is usually configured during compilation, sometimes - via a dedicated setting in application configuration.

For those "third-party" apps which are intended to be installed to `/opt/` or other "special locations", like `/usr/local` the path to application data is calculated from the path of the application, which in turn is often determined from application binary location, which is known right from `main()` arguments. Certainly your case may require a special layout, but it's useful to keep in mind these considerations.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers. As I understand now getting the path is overly complicated and not compatible across platforms. It seems to be better to embed the file in the executable.

**Edit**: I have found

http://www.fourmilab.ch/xd/

which is really easy to use.